# VSCode - HTMLHint extension has been deprecated! Where is alternatives?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, lint

As you may know VSCode's extension [HTMLHint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint) has been deprecated. It was a great static analyzer for html files. None of the alternative extensions work correctly (htmllint, LintHTML, W3C Validation...).

Maybe you can suggest better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to install [HTML-validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=html-validate.vscode-html-validate). By default is doesn't works, additionally you need to install:

```
npm install --global html-validate
```

and restart your VSCode.

If for you (as for me) is very annoying all validation rules, then you should create file `.htmlvalidate.json` into project root and fill it like this:

`{ "elements": [ "html5" ], "extends": [ "html-validate:recommended" ], "rules": { "attr-delimiter": "off", "attr-spacing": "off", "doctype-html": "off", "meta-refresh": "off", "no-conditional-comment": "off", "no-deprecated-attr": "off", "no-redundant-for": "off", "no-redundant-role": "off", "no-style-tag": "off", "prefer-button": "warn", "prefer-tbody": "off", "tel-non-breaking": "off", "unrecognized-char-ref": "off", "attribute-allowed-values": "warn", "no-trailing-whitespace": "off", "no-inline-style": "off", "doctype-style": "off", "class-pattern": "off", "attribute-empty-style": "off", "attribute-boolean-style": "off", "attr-pattern": "off", "input-missing-label": "off", "no-autoplay": "off", "element-permitted-content": "off" } }`

All rules are here: [HTML-rules](https://html-validate.org/rules/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the HTMLHint team and we recently published the official HTMLHint VS Code extension which is based on Microsoft's deprecated one. Its bundled with the latest HTMLHint library so all rules are supported out of the box and we have more features and improvements planned!

Download:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HTMLHint.vscode-htmlhint

Comment: Good news but it does not works at all

Comment: So the "Mike Kaufman" one is from Microsoft?  Curious why MS wouldn't want to maintain it, as it's such a popular extension.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work great, with all the same options OOTB.  Thank you for providing and maintaining this!!